# How to build Qt designer project only in Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I am quite new to Qt environment.

I would like to add/change some code in Qt designer source code. 
And would like to see the changes by building it in Qt Creator.

I have installed Qt Creator 3.0.0.
And I have downloaded qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4.zip.

I started the Qt Creator and build the project, and opened qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/tools/designer/designer.pro

It parses without any error. 
And when I start Run button, 
I got this compile output:

In file included from ../../../designer/src/lib/uilib/abstractformbuilder.cpp:42:0:
../../../designer/src/lib/uilib/abstractformbuilder.h:51:29: fatal error: QtGui/QSizePolicy: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make2: *** [abstractformbuilder.o] Error 1

I have found this file in qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/include/QtGui/QSizePolicy

I guess, it should add it. But I do not know why it does not find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

If anyone knows different source code for Qt Designer(only) where I can build in Qt Creator, would be also nice.

The main purpose for me, is to change/add some code to the source code of Qt Designer to fit my interest. If I can achieve i by compiling another way, rather than in Qt creator, I would be happy to get instructions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the Qt designer build system in Qt4 supports building designer individually, against another already installed Qt. I'm not sure why that should block you from modifying designer though, you can build all of Qt, possibly disabling some unneeded features such as qtwebkit. In Qt 5, designer is more decoupled from the Qt core libraries, there it's a part of qttools (https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qttools).

Comment: Let me make it clear for me. So you suggest to build the whole QT, and then make changes in QT designer. As I understood you correctly, I need to compile it myself, not in Qt Creator. Is it what you are saying? Sorry for questioning it again.

Comment: And one more thing, how can I disable unneeded features while building/compiling Qt. Thanks.

Comment: Usually one runs "configure" on the command line to build Qt. See `./configure -help` for options. (such as -no-webkit to disable QtWebkit)

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 1):

> I started the Qt Creator and build the project, and opened qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/tools/designer/designer.pro

You cannot build designer on its own with Qt 4. You would need to build the whole software to get the designer included. That is, you would need to open the main `projects.pro` in qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4 directly.

However, it would probably be more beneficial if you grabbed Qt 5's designer in the first place since that is the currently developed major Qt version. Please follow these steps in order to accomplish that:

- git clone git@gitorious.org:qt/qttools.git
- Open the `qttools.pro inside that with your QtCreator.
- Modify the source code as wished.
- Build.

Please note that if you make changes, considering upstreaming them so that others can use the features or fixes you write for the software. You can contribute that through the [Gerrit code review instance](https://codereview.qt-project.org/).

Comment: git clone git@gitorious.org:qt/qttools.git, Can not clone it. Error: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: @user3185491: create a gitorious account and upload your SSH key, or use this command instead: `git clone https://git.gitorious.org/qt/qttools.git`.

Comment: Hi, sorry. But it is failing again: "error: Failed connect to git.gitorious.org:3128; Connection timed out while accessing https://git.gitorious.org/qt/qttools.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
"

Comment: @user3185491: try again. It might be that gitorious is flaky. Other than that, I have no clue. It is a simple fetch, and works for many people daily.

Comment: I have cloned it. I will try to build it. Will come back.

Comment: Hi again. I tried to build qttools.pro in Qt Creator 5, but it gives this Compile Output: make:                                     Entering directory `/home/amrullokhuja/Desktop/qttools'
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o qttools     -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11     ... tenth lines like this, and then

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qttools] Error 1
14:52:35: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qttools (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'                                           Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I build it outside of Qt Creator, with configure, make,make install and it is just working fine. Btw, how can I fix that problem?

Comment: Configure the kit properly.